# How to enable user location with Java using Mapbox v10?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

Mapbox v10 was apparently rewritten in Kotlin and there is very little documentation about how to use the SDK in a Java application. The [user location example in the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-tracking/) contains the following block:

```
private fun initLocationComponent() {
    val locationComponentPlugin = mapView.location
    locationComponentPlugin.updateSettings {
        this.enabled = true
        this.locationPuck = ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The SDK uses a plugin architecture that uses many extension functions; the extension function `mapView.location` is not accessible from Java. I was able to get a reference to the plugin via:

```java
LocationComponentPlugin plugin = (LocationComponentPlugin) mMapView.getPlugin(Plugin.MAPBOX_LOCATION_COMPONENT_PLUGIN_ID);
```

I then enable the plugin via:

```
plugin.setEnabled(true);
```

However, to update the settings, `plugin.updateSettings()` must be called. As referenced in the documentation, that function usually takes a block of code within which settings can be updated using Kotlin. The `updateSettings()` source looks like this:

```
public abstract fun updateSettings(block: com.mapbox.maps.plugin.locationcomponent.generated.LocationComponentSettings.() -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit
```

How might that function be called from Java?

Answer (score 0):

Its really frustrating how the mapbox SDK v10 is setup for Kotlin and seemingly little thought to how Java users can access it.  I found a workaround for this issue by creating a Kotlin helper class which I can call from Java in order to access the syntax required:

```
class KtNonsense {
    companion object {
        fun doTheThing(mapView: MapView, act: AppCompatActivity) {
            val locationComponentPlugin = mapView.location
            locationComponentPlugin.updateSettings {
                this.enabled = true
                this.locationPuck = LocationPuck2D(
                        bearingImage = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                                act, //this@LocationTrackingActivity,
                                R.drawable.mapbox_user_puck_icon,
                        ),
                        shadowImage = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                                act, //this@LocationTrackingActivity,
                                R.drawable.mapbox_user_icon_shadow,
                        ),
                        scaleExpression = interpolate {
                            linear()
                            zoom()
                            stop {
                                literal(0.0)
                                literal(0.6)
                            }
                            stop {
                                literal(20.0)
                                literal(1.0)
                            }
                        }.toJson()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then can call that within the Java Activity class like this:

```
 KtNonsense.Companion.doTheThing( mapView, this );
```

This activates the user location 'puck' for me.   Note, I also implemented the required permission request for FINE and COARSE LOCATION in the normal java way

```
        if( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
...
```

and I also registered a LocationManager to get updates back to my activity - I use this to set the Camera location for the map on the first update

```
           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this );
```

Also note, having only been using Java before, I had to add Kotlin compilation plugin to my build.gradle (I think it has to be before the com.android.application plugin so it will compile the kotlin first (in build.gradle at app level):

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and also in build.gradle at project level:

```
...
buildscript {
...
   dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.21"
...
```

Anyway - that got it working for me.  If there are any Mapbox devs reading this - is there a better way?  Can you make an easier way to access your product from Java?